# Javascript Quote inside of a String?

Tags: javascript, string

I seem to have come up with a problem with my JS code. I am trying to create a string with a double quote such as 'This is a "test" string', and nothing seems to be working. The weird thing is that I can make the string "This is a 'test' string", and it seems to pass fine. My code is below as well as two live examples showing the two strings in action. My ultimate goal is to get the double quotation INSIDE the string and for the function to call and generate when the generate button is pressed (see live examples).
Thanks!

First Live Example (string = 'Kindle Fire HDX 7" 16GB')
http://hawkgen.com/gen2/

Second Live Example (string = "Kindle Fire HDX 7' 16GB") 
http://hawkgen.com/gen/

Here is the code where the string is contained:

```
        SList.slist2 = {
         "amazon": ["Kindle Fire HDX 7' 16GB", 'Kindle Charger', 'Kindle Fire HDX'],
         "apple": ['MacBook', 'iMac', 'iPhone', 'iPad'],
         "keurig": ['Platinum', 'Vue'],
         "nike": ['Fuel Band']
        };
SList.scontent = {
 "Kindle Fire HDX 7' 16GB": 'kindlefire7',
 'Kindle Charger': 'kindlecharge',
 'Kindle Fire HDX': 'kindlefirehdx',
 'MacBook': 'macbook',
 'iMac': 'imac',
 'iPhone': 'iphone',
 'iPad': 'ipad',
 'Platinum': 'platinum',
 'Vue': 'vue',
 'FuelBand': 'fuelband'
};
```

Here is the full code if needed:

```
   <!-- The first select list -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons-core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="forms.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="forms-r.css">
    <center>
    <form class="pure-form">
    <select name="slist1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
     <option>- - -</option>
     <option value="amazon">Amazon</option>
     <option value="apple">Apple</option>
     <option value="keurig">Keurig</option>
     <option value="nike">Nike</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Tags for the seccond dropdown list, and for text-content -->
    <span id="slist2"></span> <div id="scontent"></div>
    <div
    <form class="pure-form">
    <input type="text" value="Code" readonly id="display">
    </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="SList.getSelect('scontent','go');" class="pure-button     pure-button-primary" value="Generate">
    </center>
    </form>

  <script>
    var choice2;
    function setChoice(value) {
        choice2 = value;

    }
    /* Script Double Select Dropdown List, from: coursesweb.net/javascript/ */
    var SList = new Object();             // JS object that stores data for options

    // HERE replace the value with the text you want to be displayed near Select
    var txtsl2 = '';

    /*
     Property with options for the Seccond select list
     The key in this object must be the same with the values of the options added in the     first select
     The values in the array associated to each key represent options of the seccond     select
    */
    SList.slist2 = {
     "amazon": ["Kindle Fire HDX 7' 16GB", 'Kindle Charger', 'Kindle Fire HDX'],
     "apple": ['MacBook', 'iMac', 'iPhone', 'iPad'],
     "keurig": ['Platinum', 'Vue'],
     "nike": ['Fuel Band']
    };


    /*
     Property with text-content associated with the options of the 2nd select list
     The key in this object must be the same with the values (options) added in each Array in "slist2" above
     The values of each key represent the content displayed after the user selects an option in 2nd dropdown list
    */

SList.scontent = {
 "Kindle Fire HDX 7' 16GB": 'kindlefire7',
 'Kindle Charger': 'kindlecharge',
 'Kindle Fire HDX': 'kindlefirehdx',
 'MacBook': 'macbook',
 'iMac': 'imac',
 'iPhone': 'iphone',
 'iPad': 'ipad',
 'Platinum': 'platinum',
 'Vue': 'vue',
 'FuelBand': 'fuelband'
};





        /* From here no need to modify */

    // function to get the dropdown list, or content
    SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
        if (option == 'go') {
            option = choice2;
        }
      document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = '';           // empty option-content

      if(SList[slist][option]) {
        // if option from the last Select, add text-content, else, set dropdown list
        if(slist == 'scontent'){;
var selected = SList[slist][option];
functions[selected]();
}
        else if(slist == 'slist2') {
          var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
          for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
            addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
          }

          document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="setChoice(this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
        }
      }
      else if(slist == 'slist2') {
        // empty the tag for 2nd select list
        document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
      }
    }

    var functions = {

        kindlefire7: function(){
    var secondPossible = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSVWY123456';
    var firstPossible = '123456';
    var firstLength = 1;
    var secondLength = 2;

    var firstString = Array.apply(null, new Array(firstLength)).map(function () {
    return firstPossible[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstPossible.length)];
    }).join('');
    var secondString = Array.apply(null, new Array(secondLength)).map(function () {
    return secondPossible[Math.floor(Math.random() * secondPossible.length)];
    }).join('');

    document.getElementById("display").value='D0FB A0A0 343' + firstString + ' 0A' + secondString

        },
        kindlecharge: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        kindlefirehdx: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        macbook: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        imac: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        iphone: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        ipad: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        platinum: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        vue: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        fuelband: function(){window.alert("func1 called")}
    }





    </script>
```

Comment: You really need to clarify this. Is it not obvious why `'This is a "test" string"` is wrong? You open with a single-quote and then close with a double-quote.

Comment: It was a typo...now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just escape the string:

```
var kindle = "Kindle Fire HDX 7\" 16GB"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it with a `\`

Comment: Sure this comment doesn't give an example but I wonder why it got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

`"` indicates the end of the string you started with `"`. You need to either *escape* it with a backslash, e.g. `"Kindle Fire HDX 7\" 16GB"`, or open and close your string with `'` so you can use a plain `"` within the string, e.g. `'Kindle Fire HDX 7" 16GB'`.

See [Values, variables, and literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals).